# Is this SQL schema flexible and optimised for a user / group + permission scenario?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, schema

After reading a lot of articles and trying different schemas I have come up with the following:
[image]

(link: https://dbdiagram.io/d/5ddd3e41edf08a25543e64b2)

My use case is the following:
Accounts can create organizations, organizations can be either Holdings or Companies. A Holding can contain sub-organizations.
Accounts must have permissions per organizations (Read, Write, Admin).
An Account can have one or multiple organizations. Also Organizations can have multiple Accounts linked to it.

I've come up with the above schema but I'd love to have opinions and feedbacks from experienced SQL developers.

Is this schema flexible enough ? Did I miss something ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What's the use for Organizations_account_link?

Unless you are tryng to use this for another logic reason then this table is not needed.

You already have the relation organization-account on the permissions table. If you want to link an account to an organization with no permissions at all you can still use that table with null or a predifined value on the access column.

Also, for scenarios where you dont have to worry about optimization or storage (small databases), on relational tables don't use Composite keys, just go for an extra primary key or id.

Besides that, this will handle your requirements. If you don't need to handle anything else like sessions, log, etc then this will do it.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is really an answer?  Can you review and see if it meets the criteria for an answer?